# joomla without a component on the main page

Tags: joomla

On the page I edit modules constitute the main page. Actually there is no need for any component out there.

I can't remove jdoc from the template because other part of the site requires it.

I wonder what is the best solution for the problem: for main page I need one template but for others another.

As far I have worked with joomla internals almost never with back-end so I guess my knowledge lack in this department.

Any hint how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something in your template like:

```
<?php 
    $menu = JSite::getMenu();
    if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which will disable the component position when on the default [home] page

Comment: In this case, assigned component will be worked but output isnot displayed in render state.